# java - how to make an xml into a hyperlink?

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add hyperlink in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel)

In my program, I am searching through an index using Lucene and I am retrieving files. I have created XML files for the retrieved docs from the Lucene's search. Now, I want to make these XML files as hyperlinks and display to the user as the search results. That is I want the XML files to be open when the user clicks on this hyperlink. Any help appreciated!?

```
for(int i=0;i<file_count;i++)
 {
  file=str+index[i]+".xml";   

JLabel label = new JLabel(file,JLabel.CENTER );

label.setOpaque(true);
label.setBackground(Color.RED);
panel.add(label) ;

label.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
if(evt.getClickCount() > 0)
{

Runtime r= Runtime.getRuntime();
   try {
       System.out.println("testing : Inside mouseclicked");
       Process p = r.exec("cmd.exe /c start "+file);
       System.out.println("opened the file");
   } catch (IOException ex) {
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
System.out.println();
}
}
}
});
 }
```

Here is the code that I have made. In this, I am suppose to get output on the screen "file_count" no of times. I am getting that but what is happening is all the links are showing the same file when clicked. Help?

Comment: Shorter question:  How do I create a hyperlink to a file?  Answer: <a href="link-to-your-file.xml">results</a>

Comment: @ChadNC: I have tried in JLabel, but there is problem with MouseClicked action! Suppose I have three files to be shown as the output and when I use JLabel's mouse clicked event, in the output panel it is showing the same file for all the three links. What to do?

Comment: @SteveH.: Not in HTML, I want in Java.

Comment: Like @ChadNC said, what have you tried? Please post some code and a specific question where/how it doesn't do what you want. Also, explain in more detail how you want to use JLabels in there -- everyone seems to be thinking you want a web app.

Comment: The Web is full of answers. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel)'s one from this site.

Comment: i have put the code and I have told what I want. Helppppppp

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: Not the immediate problem, but don't use `JLabel`/`MouseListener`, instead use something like `JButton`/`ActionListener` or `JList`/`ListSelectionListener`.  The latter two combos. respond to both mouse **and keyboard**.

Answer (score 2):

If I do understand your question correctly, you want to allow the user to open a file. The [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class (available as of JDK1.6) allows this

```
File fileToOpen = ...;
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open( fileToOpen )
```

Depending on how you want to present this to the user, you can opt for your `JLabel` code with the listener but it is probably easier to use a `JButton` with an `ActionListener`. Both approaches are discussed in detail in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel) Marko Topolnik already suggested in his comment. The only difference is that they wanted to open an URL, while you want to open a file (so that answer uses the `browse` method instead of the `open` method of the `Desktop` class).

Comment: +1 A [`HyperlinkListener` in a `JEditorPane`](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html) is another approach.