# clickable email address as a JLabel in java

Tags: java, swing, email, jlabel, clickable

For the "About" dialog of my application, 
I have a JLabel which I have defined using html tag as follows:

```
JLabel myEmail = new JLabel(
    "<html><br><font size=2><a href=mailto:abc.pqr@xyz.com>abc.pqr@xyz.com</a>" +
    "</font></html>");`
```

I want that on clicking this `JLabel`, the default email client (say Outlook) gets opened with the `To` field populated as `abc.pqr@xyz.com` and `subject` as a predefined text (say, `Hi!`).

How to do that?

Comment: If you are using Java >= 6, you can use the Desktop API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add hyperlink in JLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet on how you could do this:

```
String address = "abc.pqr@xyz.com"; // global

JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><br><font size=2><a href=#>" + address + "</a></font></html>");
label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().mail(new URI("mailto:" + address + "?subject=Hello"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

For demonstration purposes, the `address` variable is global here but you should use a concrete `MouseAdapter` subclass to pass in the associated email address. Best to steer clear of attempting to parse the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, HTML links within a JLabel are not "clickable" by default. Please, see this topic: [How to add hyperlink in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel). It contains everything you may need to know about this topic.

Comment: I found an example which uses Desktop.getDesktop().mail(...)
Believe it should do my purpose. However, do I need to get the external jar for "java.awt.Desktop" as I am not able to import the same so as to use the mail() api.

Comment: *java.awt* is part of the core API so it doesn't any special Jars. Check which version of Java you are using. The Desktop API was only added in Java 6

Answer (score 1):

Or if you do not mind using an extra library, you can consider using the `JXHyperLink` from the SwingX project