# Hyperlinks not firing in JTable

Tags: java, swing

I tried using a custom `TableCellRenderer` that extends `JLabel` - This displays just what I want.
By default `JLabel` 'recognizes' HTML

```
`<html><body><img src='http://www......jpg'><br>Some Text
<a href='http://www.myDomain.com'>Click Here</a>Some More Text</body></html>`
```

But `JLabel` does not implement `addHyperlinkListener`, so a click on the link is never honored.

If I then try the same with `TableCellRenderer` that extends **`JTextPane`**, then the 'image' is not displayed, just the default 'broken' image.
In this case `JTextPane` does implement `addHyperlinkListener`, but again it is not honored. (Yes, I created a listener.)

If I then try the same with `TableCellRenderer` that extends **`JEditorPane`**, then again the 'image' is not displayed, just the default 'broken' image.
In this case `JTextPane` does implement `addHyperlinkListener`, but again it is not honored. (Yes, I created a listener.)

Answer (score 4):

No matter how many listeners you register to the components returned by the `TableCellRenderer`, they will never be called. The component is not contained in the table but only used as a stamp. As a result, events will never reach those listeners. This concept is explained in the [Swing table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) (in the Renderers and Editors section).

You can take a look at the [Table Button column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) example which adds a clickable button in a `JTable`. The same concept can be used to include a hyperlink in a `JTable`.

You might also find the following SO question about ["Adding a hyperlink in a `JLabel`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel) interesting.