# hyperlink to open in browser in java?

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, awt, jbutton

Is there a way to set `ac.getPage()` as a hyperlink to open in broswer when clicked on? `ac.getPage()` returns a `string` which is an actual fact a url of a persons blog. I tried attaching the following `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(ac.getPage())` and error says `void` is not allowed? How can i correct this?

```
pageLabel.setText("Page:    " + ac.getPage());
```

Comment: seems similar with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel

Comment: @JoopEggen yes i did that

Comment: @Mahan that seems too long and i would like to be able to keep the text "Page" too

Comment: 1) Alternately use a `JTextField` for the link component as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13871898/418556). A text field is an accessible component.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: That "void is not allowed" seems to be caused by the `void browse(URI)`. Do you assign it? Is a semicolon `;` missing before that code? `browse` opens the system browser with an URI.

Comment: @JoopEggen tried the following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLek4Ycb7p8&list=PLB04B4E5D9B58C13D&index=76

if there is a way for Jlabel to work with mouselisterner should do it?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a JTextPane instead of a JLabel,

```
JTextPane pageLabel = new JTextPane();
pageLabel.setEditable(false);
pageLabel.setText("<html>Page: <a href='http://eo.wikipedia.org/'>vikipedio</a>"):
pageLabel.addHyperLinkListener(new HyperLinkListener() {
    @Override
    public hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            String url = event.getURL().toString();
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(url));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Depends on the context of the OP's question, but this might be a bit of an overkill...

Comment: It is an answer to the comment with youtube in it.