# How do I add an ActionListener to an instance of my class that extends JButton?

Tags: java, swing, events, uri, jbutton

I instantiated a button of my class like so:

```
linkBtn = new LinkButton(
                        new URI("http://www.example.com"),
                        "Click me");
```

Nothing happens when I click it, so I want to add an action listener something like this:

```
linkBtn.addActionListener(SOMETHING);
```

I tried things like this:

```
linkBtn.addActionListener(new LinkButton.OpenUrlAction());
```

That gives the following error:

> an enclosing instance that contains LinkButton.OpenUrlAction is
>   required

I haven't found the right syntax yet.

Here's my class that extends JButton:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class LinkButton extends JButton
    implements ActionListener {
    /** The target or href of this link. */
    private URI target;
    final static private String defaultText = "<HTML>Click the <FONT color=\"#000099\"><U>link</U></FONT>"
        + " to go to the website.</HTML>";

    public LinkButton(URI target, String text) {
        super(text);
        this.target = target;
        //this.setText(text);
        this.setToolTipText(target.toString());
    }
    public LinkButton(URI target) {
        this( target, target.toString() );
    }    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        open(target);
    }
    class OpenUrlAction implements ActionListener {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        open(target);
      }
    }
    private static void open(URI uri) {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
      try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
      } catch (IOException e) { /* TODO: error handling */ }
    } else { /* TODO: error handling */ }
  }
}
```

Comment: See also [`LinkLabel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13871898/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I got my idea from LinkLabel, but I want a button. I'm open to suggestions other than my approach. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm open to suggestions. I don't like my program structure either...

The answer's provided so far are all excellent.

Hovercraft has suggest the use of `Action`s, which would simply the structure of your code.

For example...

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LinkButtonExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LinkButtonExample();
    }

    public LinkButtonExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    frame.add(new JButton(new OpenURLAction(new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/"))));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class OpenURLAction extends AbstractAction {

        private URL url;

        public OpenURLAction(URL url) {

            this("<HTML>Click the <FONT color=\\\"#000099\\\"><U>link</U></FONT> to go to the website.</HTML>", url);

        }

        public OpenURLAction(String text, URL url) {

            putValue(NAME, text);
            setURL(url);

        }

        public void setURL(URL url) {
            this.url = url;
            setEnabled(
                            url != null
                            && Desktop.isDesktopSupported()
                            && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE));
            putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, url == null ? null : url.toString());
        }

        public URL getURL() {
            return url;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (isEnabled()) {

                URL url = getURL();
                if (url != null && Desktop.isDesktopSupported()
                                && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
                    } catch (    IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Check out [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you extends a `JButton` but you can add by default this listener in constructor.

```
 public LinkButton(URI target, String text) {
        super(text);
        this.target = target;
        //this.setText(text);
        this.setToolTipText(target.toString());
        this.addActionListener(this);
        //this.addActionListener(new OpenUrlAction());
    }
```

Or you can do this.

`linkBtn.addActionListener(linkBtn.new OpenUrlAction());`
   [outerObject.new InnerClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Or you can modify your inner class with a `constructor injection`

```
class OpenUrlAction implements ActionListener{
  private URI target;

  OpenUrlAction(URI target){
   this.target=target;
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
     open(this.target);
  }
}
```

In client code:

```
`linkBtn.addActionListener(linkBtn.new OpenUrlAction(lninkBtn.getTarget)); // or the target that you want`
```

Comment: Didn't you do an example where the `OpenURLAction` took a `URL` parameter and then added that to the button?  That was a decent example

Comment: @MadProgrammer i added again xD

Comment: See, that's a nice idea ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
linkBtn.addActionListener(linkBtn.new OpenUrlAction());
```

But your program structure makes me wince. Myself I'd try to get Actions separate from views. I also much prefer extension by composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. I don't like my program structure either... but I'm just working from examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I came up with so far. I added this method to my LinkButton class:

```
public void init() {
    this.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Then I added this code to add the action listener:

```
linkBtnDonate.init();
```

It's working. I'm open to other suggestions.