# adding Hyperlinks on history of web browser

Tags: java

I am developing a web browser in java,storing URLs in a file and displaying them in html page now how I would add hyperlinks on URLs.

Comment: Please see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is "how do I add hyperlinks in Java", you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/527877/1843508